# Spring Webflux - how to get value from Flux without block() operations

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I wonder how to write non-blocking code with Webflux.

Here is what I want to do:

1. Get all Products by `ProductProperties` field (returned as Flux)
2. Get a list of values from `Flux<Product>.availabilityCalendar` 
   Use the data retrieved in step 2 and fetch some other data (returned as Flux<>) - everything should be a non-blocking operations.

How to do that? How to get values from `Flux<Object>` and then fetch some other data returned as Flux<> avoiding blocking operations like Flux.block() to retrieve data that are needed in the next step to fetch final data to return?

```
    public Flux<Product> getAllProductsByAvailability(Flux<ProductProperties> productProperties,
                Map<String, String> searchParams) {

    productProperties
                    .flatMap(property -> productRepository.findByProductPropertiesId(property.getId())) //1. return Products
                    .flatMap(product -> Flux.just(product.getAvailabilityCalendar())) //2. how to get Product.availabilityCalendar list as non-blocking operation to work with this data afterwards?
(...)
```

where:

1. `productRepository.findByProductPropertiesId` returns Flux
2. Product has field: `ArrayList<ProductAvailability> availabilityCalendar`

Is it a good approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

like this 
I check the tag valid

```
 Flux.fromIterable(vo.getTags())
        .flatMap((tag) -> tagService.findByCode(tag.getCode()).map(TagBo::createByVo)).filter(Objects::nonNull).collectList().doOnNext(l->vo.setTags(l));
```

Answer (score -1):

by using the onNext parameter

```
productRepository.findByProductPropertiesId(property.getId())
.onNext(product -> {
    return // Do things here
})
```